# Canvas addeventlistener click image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add an eventlistener to a picture so once clicked it takes me to a different page, at the moment I have it taking me to the next page but not when I click the picture, but when I click anywhere on the canvas

Comment: Show some code. A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example showing the problem would be advantageous, but not required

Comment: I wouldn't call vague assumption a talent. Coding without knowing all the facts and offering answers without knowing the source of the problem is an extremely obnoxious trait. But by all means, live your life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Responding to canvas click events**

**Oops**, it looks like your question was cut off!  On your next question, be sure not to hit the “Enter” key—instead of starting a new line in your question, you will immediately post your partially written question (don’t worry…we’ve all done it).

And Nick, “Welcome to stackoverflow” – it really is full of answers!

Norguard is right about the canvas not being able to keep track of which image you clicked on.  Think of canvas as an artist's easel and you are painting images on that easel.  Yes, the easel contains the images, but the easel has no way of knowing where you drew any image.

To keep your life simple while you’re learning, try starting with having just 1 image per canvas (yes, you can have as many canvas elements as you have images).

If you want to start with 1 image per canvas, here is code and a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/KGKYg/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
      canvas.width=img.width;
      canvas.height=img.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }
    img.src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/139992952/coffee.png";

    canvas.addEventListener("click", function (e) { alert("use your linke totake me away...!"); }); 

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**[Edit: Responding to keyboard events]**

Here's how you can listen for user keypresses and respond to them:

```
// listen for keyboard events
window.addEventListener('keydown',keyIsDown,true);

// process the keystrokes
function keyIsDown(event){

    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 38:
            // "UP" was pressed, do UP stuff
            break;
        case 40:
            // "DOWN" was pressed, do DOWN stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah it does seem to my question did get cut off :P thanks for the answer, the problem I've got is that its a menu in a game so need 2/3 "links" for play shop etc. Would it be possible to use the up and down arrows or would that be more complicated?

Comment: Not complicated--see my edited answer above.  Whether to use keypresses to drive a menu is your design decision, but it's not complicated. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this simply, and there's no event listener that will let you.

1) listen for the click on the canvas
2) keep a reference to the image object that you drew...  ...as in, know its canvas coordinates, by keeping reference in a separate object:

```
var canvas_img = {
    x : 250,
    y : 300,
    data   : my_img, 
    width  : my_img.width,
    height : my_img.height
};
```

3) on click of the canvas, manually calculate whether a collision happened between where the click happened on the canvas, and where the image is on the canvas.